# Restore / Create a database with a data file (MDF) from backup the same but with two data files (MDF and NDF)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I must restore/create a db (in a new instance) in one file(mdf) from a backup of the same but with two files of data (mdf and ndf)

**How can I do it?**

---

This is what I try... but it did not work

```
    RESTORE database mydb
    FROM  DISK='\\150.10.10.12\backup\mydb.bak' 
    WITH  REPLACE, RECOVERY, 
    MOVE 'Mydb_DATOS'       TO 'F:\MSSQL\Data\Mydb.mdf', 
    MOVE 'Mydb_REGISTRO'    TO 'G:\MSSQL\LOG\Mydb_LOG.ldf'
```

then check the following

```
 RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
 DISK='\\150.10.10.12\backup\mydb.bak'
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the .NDF file in your restore script.

```
 RESTORE DATABASE mydb
    FROM  DISK='\\150.10.10.12\backup\mydb.bak' 
    WITH  
        REPLACE
      , RECOVERY
      , MOVE 'IMAGENES_Data' TO 'F:\MSSQL\Data\Mydb.mdf'
      , MOVE 'IMAGENES'      TO 'F:\MSSQL\Data\Mydb.ndf' 
      , MOVE 'IMAGENES_Log'  TO 'G:\MSSQL\LOG\Mydb_LOG.ldf';
```

Comment: In the new instance i can restore all db in only file mdf?

Comment: @diegoxfs During a restore, you cannot merge your non-MDF files into the MDF file. You could restore the database and then move your data to the MDF, empty the NDF file(s), and then drop them.